# Html table converting into a png image by java

Tags: java, html, image, png

I use  html2image librarie to convert  a html table into  a png image ,but it doesn't work for me because it doesn't preserve the style and the look and feel of the table.
here's the test code that i use

```
System.out.println("convertion start")
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
imageGenerator.loadHtml("<div style=\"border: medium solid #4D5820; direction:rtl; width:530px;\"><table border=\"1\">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table> </div>");

imageGenerator.saveAsImage("priere123.png");
System.out.println("End génération");
```

So my question is if html2png.jar doesn't preserve styling,is there any java framework that gives the possiblity to read from an url and parse the html content for  tables and convert it to a png image that perserves the style of the html content.

Thank you

Comment: Is html2image for Java?

Comment: what does the output look like? Please provide the image.

Comment: the output specially is like a timesheet table with some sytling  in the cells that i want to preserve,and to convert  into a png image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use [WebVector](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/webvector/). It's a very simple application based on CSSBox. When you take a look at its source code, you should be able to integrate it with your application quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

CSSbox might be of interest to you http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/